# Is it time consuming to print log in exec command?

Tags: php, background, exec, logfile

In PHP,

I am running exec command in php script so that It will run in `background`. But I'm wondering about the performance hit when logging to log_file?

```
exec("/usr/bin/php /path/to/Notification.php >> /path/to/log_file.log 2>&1 &");
```

If so then how can I not print output to log_file? I know `/dev/null`. But I don't know correct syntax or structure. Please Can anyone append me this on above line.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by 'is it take time to print log'?

Comment: I mean that whether it will time consuming to print log rather than not print log

Answer (score 1):

since you are appending to the log file through the bash output redirection, it will be very good in terms of performance.
Everything depends ofcourse on how much output that is being logged and how big your log file is, if you aren't rotating it properly.

If this is too excessive, you can disable the output redirection, simply by removing everything after the `>>` output redirection directive:

```
exec("/usr/bin/php /path/to/Notification.php &");
```

this however could still output to the system's `stdout` or `stderr`, to skip this redirect all output to `/dev/null` as you mentioned:

```
exec("/usr/bin/php /path/to/Notification.php &> /dev/null &");
```

[here is a good reference](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html) about output redirection in bash

please also note that `$>` is bash only.